# How can I deploy an AWS Lambda function from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment, aws-lambda

I have a simple Lambda function that I'm trying to deploy through Jenkins -

```
public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
        String output = "";
        if (input.isEmpty()) {
            output = "No input provided";
        } else {
            output = "Hello, " + input + "! Checking invocation - 1";
        }
        return output;
    }
```

I'm able to deploy and invoke this through Eclipse's AWS Lambda plugin without any problems.

I'm using the AWS Lambda plugin for Jenkins and following their [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWS+Lambda+Plugin).

- I'm providing my [Git repository](https://github.com/anishsana/HelloFunction/) as the source.
- Artifact Location - `src/main/java/`
- Handler Name - `lambda.Hello` (*lambda* is the package name and *Hello* is the class name). I've also tried using `lambda.Hello.handleRequest`,  `lambda.Hello::handleRequest` and other variations.

Jenkins says that the build was successful but when I test it on the AWS console, I'm getting -

```
"errorMessage": "Class not found: lambda.Hello",
  "errorType": "class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
```

Where am I going wrong here? When I export the test function from AWS and unzip it, I can see that code on Git definitely got deployed but it's unable find the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution while trying to manually deploy the Lambda function as a jar file. These are the steps -

- Create your Lambda function as a Maven project using the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-no-ide.html).
- Create your Jenkins job as a Maven project and specify `package` in the goals section.
- Follow the Jenkins Lambda plugin [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWS+Lambda+Plugin) for deployment and specify `target/your-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` as the Artifact location.

This should build your Lambda function with Maven and then deploy it to AWS.